# Identify window not opening in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, identify

My identify window no longer appears when I identify a feature in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a registry issue.

1. Start regedit.
2. Navigate to HKey_Current_User\Software\ESRI\ArcMap\IdentifyResultsDialog\IdentifyWindowsPos. 3. Modify the IdentifyWindowPos key to a value such as 20,20,400,400.

More information may be found in [Bug: The Identify Results window does not display](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004902).

Comment: not too hard: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=21485

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is:

```
  go to this directory
```

C:\Users\your-user-name-here\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.8\ArcMap\Templates

rename

> Normal.mxt

to any other name, for example,

> Normal_org.mxt

Done

Your identify popup window will popup normally.

mal-function template file cause the problem. When you rename it. a new freshed template file generated. fixed the problem.

[image: fix]