# ArcGIS 9.3.1 on Windows 7 (64 bit) identify tool won't display

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I have installed the arcgis editor student version 9.3.1, but the identify tool does not display.

I tried the options described in the link:

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21485

I change my screen resolution first to a lower one since the settings were in the highest, restarted my computer, opened arcmap, changed to a higher resolution several times and nothing.  I also tried to follow the path but I do not have the `Identifyresultsdialog` option either. I can only get to `HKey_Current_User\Software\ESRI\ArcMap\`

Any other solutions?

Identify is sooo necessary!

I am using windows 7 professional version 6.1

Answer (score 1):

Related

[How do I open the Identify window in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/how-do-i-open-the-identify-window-in-arcmap)

Answer (score 0):

There's another registry setting for the dialog in HKey_Current_User\Software\ESRI\ArcCatalog\IdentifyResultsDialog

Comment: HKey_Current_User\Software\ESRI\ArcCatalog\IdentifyResultsDialog
ArcCatalog does not have it either (the identifyresultsdialog option) I cannot get to it

Comment: This registry value won't show up until you use the Identify tool in ArcCatalog

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an odd problem, can you check the hash sum of your install and have you tried a Re-install?