# Identify Results window not displaying in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, identify, arcgis-10.5

When using the **Identify tool** in **ArcMap 10.5**, the feature that is identified flashes, but the ***Identify Results window does not display***.

I found the following article in esri support pages:
http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004902 . However, this post does not cover my current ArcGIS version:
ArcGIS Dektop 10.5
Version: 10.5.0.6491
License type: Advanced

I tried to follow [How do I open the Identify window in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2545) , but that did not solve the problem:

> "...Start regedit. Navigate to
>   HKey_Current_User\Software\ESRI\ArcMap\IdentifyResultsDialog\IdentifyWindowsPos.
>   Modify the IdentifyWindowPos key to a value such as 20,20,400,400.
>   More information may be found in Article ID: 21485 The Identify
>   Results window does not display."

My installed applications:

- ArcCatalog 10.5.0.6491
- ArcGlobe 10.5.0.6491
- ArcMap 10.5.0.6491
- ArcScene 10.5.0.6491

Microsoft Windows10
Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.1066)

Comment: Did you update to 10.5 from a previous version?  Did the Identify window work on that version?  Are you running multiple monitors (or have you in the past)?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the task bar and selecting "Cascade windows"? That may not be the precise phrase, since I'm on my smartphone.

Comment: @Midavalo - Yes; when I installed ArcMap I was working with multiple monitors (and Identify window was working fine).  Now I am with a single monitor, and that's when the trouble started

Comment: @kenbuja - Tried "Cascade windows" too, but still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you moved your Identify window onto another monitor when you had multiple monitors attached and then switched to single monitor, you will find that Identify window is still in the same location on the other monitor!

Two ways to fix this:

1. Connect another monitor, find and move your Identify window back into the ArcMap screen then disconnect second monitor
2. *Sometimes* the window moves so that you can see a very small portion of it on the edge of your active monitor.  Look closely at the edge of your screen to see if there is just the border of the window there.  If so you may be able to grab it (even enough just to resize it a bit) and then drag the window into your main screen.

Once it is where you want it, close and reopen ArcMap to have it save the window location.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me with 10.6.1.

Sometimes the window moves so that you can see a very small portion of it on the edge of your active monitor. Look closely at the edge of your screen to see if there is just the border of the window there. If so you may be able to grab it (even enough just to resize it a bit) and then drag the window into your main screen.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me using ArcCatalog 10.8 to run tools from home on a remote desktop to my work laptop where I had been running tools across three monitors.  After clicking OK to start the tool to run it with foreground geoprocessing (which I usually prefer) the Results window did not appear so I assumed it was trying to run on another monitor that I could not see.  I tried deleting the Normal.gxt to reset ArcCatalog but that did not seem to fix it.

Then I inadvertently clicked on the ArcCatalog banner (above the Menu bar) and the Results window jumped back on screen.  Consequently, whether you are using a geoprocessing tool like I was, or the Identify tool as in the question, I think it is worth clicking the top bar of whichever ArcGIS Desktop 10.x application you are using (ArcCatalog, ArcMap, ArcScene, ArcGlobe) to see if that fixes it for you.

---

I just tested using ArcGIS 10.5 on Windows 7 SP1, and I have no trouble using the Identify button to open the Identify window.

Consequently, I think you should follow the advice of the note in [Bug: The Identify Results window does not display](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004902):

> If this issue is experienced on a version other than what is listed,
> please contact Esri Technical Support for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is:

```
  go to this directory
```

C:\Users\your-user-name-here\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.8\ArcMap\Templates

rename

> Normal.mxt

to any other name, for example,

> Normal_org.mxt

Done

Your identify popup window will popup normally.

mal-function template file cause the problem. When you rename it. a new freshed template file generated. fixed the problem.

[image: how to fix]